# Java UI on macOS X Lion

Tags: java, macos

I'm having a strange bug wich i suspect to be specific to either MacOS X Lion and/or Java VM implementation on this OS.

When a java app summons a secondary window like a dialog box, i'm often unable to interact with its content ie. click, use menus, etc.

At first i though my app was buggy but since i had developped it on windows (where it worked fine) and switched to mac. I though some weird swing setting was to blame and i had noticed on the console that a compatibility mode with cocoa was enabled when i launched my app.

But i encountered the same bug with eclipse itself (a well known java based ide) tough it does not always happen in it while it's all the time with my app.

I have browsed for this issue but found nothing. Meanwhile i found that there is an issue between oracle and apple about java. I downladed a java update specific to Lion but the bug is still here

My question is : have you encountered the same bug ? is it macos lion specific ? have you found a workaround ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Made some research. Eclipse seems to be the cause of the bug. More precisely SWT support in eclipse under MacOS environnement.

The bug is not present with netbeans.